# Angular RxJS - How to use async pipe instead of subscribing, no properties, no directives in template?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, ag-grid-angular

I have this injectable service:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SharedEventService {
    public addButtonEnabledSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
    public readonly addButtonEnabled$ = this.addButtonEnabledSubject.asObservable();
}
```

There's this component with a button that should trigger the shared observable event:

```
@Component({...})
export class WidgetContainerComponent {
    public constructor(private readonly sharedEventService: SharedEventService) {}

    protected onAddLineItem(): void {
        this.sharedEventService.addButtonEnabledSubject.next(true);
    }
}
```

```html
<button (click)="onAddLineItem()" mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon svgIcon="add-li"></mat-icon>
    <br/>
    Add a new line item
</button>
```

Then I have this other component that renders an [Ag Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/getting-started/) and should listen when the shared event is triggered by the above button:

```
@Component({...})
export class GridComponent {
    private api!: GridApi;
    public constructor(private readonly sharedEventService: SharedEventService) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line rxjs-angular/prefer-async-pipe -- struggle to refactor this to async pipe:
        this.sharedEventService.addButtonEnabled$.subscribe(() => this.addRow());
    }

    private addRow(): void {
        this.api.applyTransaction({
            add: [{}]
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="resource-ag-grid-content">
    <ag-grid-angular class='resource-grid ag-theme-material'
        [rowData]='rowData'
        [columnDefs]='columnDefs'
        [components]='components'
        [context]='getContext()'
        [gridOptions]='gridOptions'
        (gridReady)='gridReady($event)'>
    </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

The code works, but how can I remove the explicit subscription to the shared observable and use an async pipe instead? Especially because I have an ESLint complaint.

I have looked at other questions but I can't figure out how to use async pipe because I'm not using any properties in the grid component. Also, since I'm using the `GridApi`, I don't know I would add the async pipe in the HTML template because there are no `ng` directives being used.

Answer (score 1):

You can't refactor it because, there is no direct relation between the component which triggers the event and the one who consumes the event,

all you have to do, is try to [unsubscribe when the component gets destroyed](https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f).